# MYSQL SELECT with 3 WHERE clause

Tags: select, mysqli, where-clause

I am having trouble with this code

```
$set = 'mycrazyemail@gmail.com'
$check_is_idk = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `ppl` WHERE `email` = '{$set}' AND `is` = 'idk' AND `belongs` = '{$id}'");
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Please tell us the error you're getting otherwise we'll have to guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the first line, it currently causes a parse error:

```
$set = 'mycrazyemail@gmail.com';
$check_is_idk = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `ppl` WHERE `email` = '{$set}' AND `is` = 'idk' AND `belongs` = '{$id}'");
```